# Android - Unable to extend ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I simply want to extend ImageView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }

}
```

But Android Studio returns the compile error:

> This custom view should extend
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instead

But importing `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` insted of `android.widget.ImageView` does not solve the problem because ImageView is marked then as not imported...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to change the `extends` part, too; not just the `import` - `public class SquareImageView extends AppCompatImageView`.

Comment: `SquareImageView extneds android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`

Answer (score 8):

This works perfectly fine

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

When you import `AppCompatImageView` then you have to use it too. Not only this, in JAVA, **what you import is what you use.putting it other way, you import what you want to use**

Comment: Looks nice, but I'm using androidx, not v7.  Which means that this import statement doesn't work (`cannot resolve symbol 'v7'`).

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for an answer and are using the **androidx** libraries, here's an update.

Yes, you still need to use `AppCompatImageView`, but just use the new libraries.  Here's the new import statement:

`import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;`

Just changing this import to this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275686/624814) should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Using `AppCompat` widgets allows you to have some features on devices with pre-Lollipop versions of Android.

Use `AppCompatImageView`,`ImageView` will be fine now.